# JavaScript function execution

Tags: javascript

Does the browser execute JavaScript functions that never get invoked?

Do these functions do any harm apart from increasing file size?

```
function test() {

     // 1000 lines of code (not commented out)

}
```

Comment: What is _dead code_??  Are you talking about code that is commented out or code that is **NOT** invoked?  Regardless of the answer, why would you want to keep either?  According to [Wikipedia's definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code), dead code is **DEFINITELY** executed.  Is that what you mean by dead code?

Comment: This depends on the browser.  Chrome has a very nice JIT for JavaScript and probably does some optimizations like skipping dead code in whatever the compiled code is written to.  However, your users will still have to download all of the code whether or not it executes after the fact.

Comment: You should edit your question to define what you mean by _dead code_.  According to [Wikipedia's definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code) _dead code_ is most certainly executed and it most certainly has negative side-effects... But I have a feeling that's not what you're talking about.

Comment: Apologies, used wrong term, wasn't aware of that. Question has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

As long as `test()` is never called, the code is never executed. It might be compiled though.

Answer (score 1):

It might parse that code, but like any other function it's not going to be executed unless *called:*

```
test(); // or any of the many other ways to call a function in JavaScript
```

Whether or not the browser parses it is likely to be implementation-dependent.

Comment: _"It might"_ depends on?

Comment: @gdoron context. For instance, if this function is inside of another never-reached block of code, it might never be parsed.

Comment: @MattBall It will always be parsed. I guess you mean compiled.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will not execute any of the code, unless it is explicitly referenced either in the code or dynamically during the running of the script.

**Example**

```
function func()
{
    alert('hello');
}

window.addEventListener('load',func,false);
// With this line it will be called on load.
```